# Prolog why my function always evaluates to true

Tags: prolog

I have the folowing code

```
isInRange(Point1,Point2,Range):-
manhatan2(Point1,Point2,Manhatan),
Range>Manhatan.
```

manhatan2 computes the manhatan distance between 2 points give in as a 2 element list [X,Y]

I don't understand why isInRange always evaluates to true

isInRange([0,0],[0,10],9) evaluates to true
isInRange([0,0],[0,10],100) also evaluates to true

I am pretty sure i did the manhatan function right.Have tested it with many values

Can anyone help me understand what is wrong with my code ?

%Edit starts here

So i traced the damn thing and here is more code i use

```
modul(A,B,R):-A<B,R is B-A.
modul(A,B,R):-A>B,R is A-B.

extractFromList([H|_],X,R):- X is 0,R is H.
extractFromList([_|T],X,R):- X1 is X-1,extractFromList(T,X1,R).

manhatan(X1,Y1,X2,Y2,R):- modul(X1,X2,R1),modul(Y1,Y2,R2),R is R1+R2.

manhatan2(P1,P2,R):-
extractFromList(P1,0,X1),
extractFromList(P1,1,Y1),
extractFromList(P2,0,X2),
extractFromList(P2,1,Y2),
manhatan(X1,Y1,X2,Y2,R).
```

The extract fromFromList extracts the Xth element from the given list

modul should return |A-B|

Tracing isInRange([0,0],[0,10],100) everthing whent as i whanted.

Tracing isInRange([0,0],[0,10],9) stoped when comparing the manhatan with the range and 
started redoing modul(0,10,_GXXX) evaluating _GXXX to -10 and thus the Manhatan < Range condition evaluated to true thus all isInRange evaluating to true

Why does it do that ?

Why does it redo the modul computation in this way ?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: 
The following code does what you want:

```
manhattan(L1,L2,Result) :- manhattan(L1,L2,0,Result).

manhattan([],[],Res,Res).
manhattan([H1|T1],[H2|T2],Acc,Res) :-
    AccNew is Acc + abs(H1-H2),
    manhattan(T1,T2,AccNew,Res).

isInRange(P1, P2, Range) :-
    manhattan(P1, P2, Distance),
    Range > Distance.
```

Longer answer:
I tried your code and it doesn't behave as you describe it.
For me, isInRange always fails, because 'modul' fails if A==B. 
You should change the test on the first case to A =< B.
Or, even better, use the builtin 'abs' function.

I assume that in your previous version you didn't have a test in the second case.
In that case Prolog will try the second case when the first case leads to failure (for example because Range > Manhatan fails).
Adding the test in the second case in one way to solve this problem.